# SQLite: %midstring% and stringstart% searching on multiple columns, but wanting successful stringstart% matches to always be returned first

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Here's a simplified version of a table I have:

```
sometable
title  |  tag   | score
-----------------------
foo1      bar       100
bar2      oobar      50
meh3                 25
```

Currently, If I want to search the table and have `oo` be my search query, I'd execute something like:

```
SELECT *, (title||" "||tag) AS titletag
FROM sometable WHERE titletag LIKE "%oo%"
ORDER BY score DESC
```

and the above would return the `foo1` row first, and `bar2` second.

What I'd like to add in, is if the search query (`oo`) matches the start of a `tag` (eg `tag LIKE "oo%"`), I want said rows to come first before any other row, regardless of score, but still retain the rest of the original query.

So by searching for `oo`, I'd want the `bar2` row returned first since `oo` matches the start of `oobar`, and then have `foo1` come second, even though `bar2`'s score is lower than `foo1`'s.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMAtm's answer didn't quite work but gave me an idea to use:

```
SELECT *, (title||" "||tag) AS titletag, score*100 AS newscore
FROM sometable WHERE tag LIKE "oo%"

UNION

SELECT *, (title||" "||tag) AS titletag, score AS newscore
FROM sometable WHERE titletag LIKE "%oo%"

ORDER BY newscore DESC
```

This way, in the first `SELECT` term, matching `tag`s are assigned a much higher score, and in the second `SELECT` term their scores stay the same.

So `bar2` would come first with a `newscore` of 5000, and `foo1` comes second because its `newscore` stays at 100.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Union`:

```
SELECT *, (title||" "||tag) AS titletag
FROM sometable WHERE titletag LIKE "oo%"

UNION

SELECT *, (title||" "||tag) AS titletag
FROM sometable WHERE titletag LIKE "%oo%"

ORDER BY score DESC
```

But you should be aware of [Maximum Number Of Terms In A Compound SELECT Statement](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no luck for what I want. `foo1` is still returned first. `WHERE titletag LIKE "oo%"` might be wrong? Tried changing it to `WHERE tag LIKE "oo%"` but made no difference. Could you take another look?

Comment: Actually, your suggestion has led me in the right direction. Let me post my answer and give you an upvote. Thanks.